# How to match entire string using RegExp VBA after a keyword

Tags: regex, excel, vba, ms-access, outlook

could anybody give me a hint regarding this issue? I want to extract everything behind 'Description : 96 pcs of '.

```
Description : 96 pcs of  99999-9XXXX*99999 XXX XX XXXX, XX/XXX XXX 9
```

Comment: What have you tried? There are lots of regular expressions websites, including ones where you can test your code.

Comment: For example, "pcs of\s+(.*)". Don't know, why it's not correct.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need Regex for this:

```
Sub qwerty()
    Dim s1 As String, s2 As String, s3 As String
    s1 = "Description : 96 pcs of  99999-9XXXX*99999 XXX XX XXXX, XX/XXX XXX 9"
    s2 = "Description : 96 pcs of"
    s3 = Mid(s1, InStr(1, s1, s2) + Len(s2))
    MsgBox s3
End Sub
```

[image]

Comment: I am sorry, I didn't provide the details. This row comes from e-mail message (Outlook).

Comment: @MaciejDrozdowski the extraction is the same................does not matter where the string came from.................. *pardon the dangling proposition.*

Comment: @MaciejDrozdowski... This is the reason, you need to provide all the necessary details before you want any solution, Also you could have given the code you are stuck with so that we could help you better. Thanks